# TableView Jumps and Resizes after moving from LGSideMenuController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am using `LGSideMenuController` for displaying side menu. When I click on the menu bar button the side menu appears(no issue here).

`LGSideMenuController` image:

[image: Image 1].

So when I click on a particular item ,it animates to the table view ... first tableview contents go little down and within fraction of seconds it resizes. I don't know why this is happening and I am unable to find the solution. Any help will be highly appreciated.
See the gif for ref.

[image: Gig image]

Comment: Make your application navigation translucent = false for every navigation

Comment: Not working bro @NitinGohel